# How can I access the root DataContext in a DataTemplate in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a grid of items which is populated using databinding.
In the grid I have a `DataTemplate` for certain cells. I need to access the `DataContext` of the root element (the one which is hosting the grid) so that I can access additional bindings to support my datatemplate.

So you have:

```
Window
    Window.DataContext = TheDataSourceWithItemsAndSupports
    DataGrid.ItemsSource = {Binding Items}
        DataTemplate
            ListBox.ItemsSource = {Binding Supports}
```

I want the `{Binding Supports}` on `TheDataSourceWithItemsAndSupports`, but I don't see how to do that. I tried specifying `{Binding}` but that always returns `null`. I also tried using `RelativeSource FindAncestor`, but that yields `null` too.

Any clues?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe try

```
Window Name="TheWindow"
...
ListBox.ItemsSource = {Binding DataContext.Supports, ElementName=TheWindow}
```

Comment: I think the binding path would be DataContext.Supports, but this was my idea as well.

Comment: This worked, but I had to do some more coding (the scenario given above wasn't an exact representation of the situation at hand).

Answer (score 4):

Another little trick to bind to your root context

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.Supports}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to expose whole DataContext class by implementing This field

```
get
{
    return this;
}
```

and then binding to it.

Answer (score 0):

It should work the way you describe. Only thing I see your DataTemplate is not ItemTemplate. You should also look at the output window to see where bindings fail.